# Cannot disable CSRF protection in Spring Security 3.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Long time ago, I turn on CSRF protection in my project by adding
    `<csrf />` in `<http></http>`:

```xml
<http auto-config='true'>
    <csrf/> //enable CSRF protection
    <headers/>
    <!-- <intercept-url pattern="**" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/> -->
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp"/>
    <remember-me key="bcp" use-secure-cookie="true"/>
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/index.jsp"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/users" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/*" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false"/>
    </session-management>
    <!-- <custom-filter ref="myFilter" before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR"/> -->
</http>
```

Today, I'd like to turn off CSRF protection. However, I tried many method but CSRF protection seems still be turned on.

The evidence showing CSRF protection is still turned on is that I saw `CSRFFilter` 
was mention in Log4j logging for Tomcat:

```
2017-09-03 12:52:33 INFO  HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser:266 - Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 300, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 700, <org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>, order = 1100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1900, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2000, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2200, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2300]
2017-09-03 12:52:33 DEBUG XmlWebApplicationContext:543 - Bean factory for Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2d28ac29: defining beans [propertyConfigurer,dataSource,sqlSessionFactoryInfosec,mapperScanner,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,requestDataValueProcessor,org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager,myUserDetailService,webexpressionHandler]; root of factory hierarchy
2017-09-03 12:52:33 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:669 - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2d28ac29: defining beans [propertyConfigurer,dataSource,sqlSessionFactoryInfosec,mapperScanner,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,requestDataValueProcessor,org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager,myUserDetailService,webexpressionHandler,userMapper,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
2017-09-03 12:52:34 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:220 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository#0'
2017-09-03 12:52:34 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:449 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository#0'
2017-09-03 12:52:34 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:523 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
2017-09-03 12:52:34 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:477 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository#0'
2017-09-03 12:52:35 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository#0'
2017-09-03 12:52:35 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository#0'
2017-09-03 12:52:35 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository#0'
2017-09-03 12:52:35 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository#0'
2017-09-03 12:52:35 INFO  DefaultSecurityFilterChain:28 - Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@179474ff, org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter@7bac2803, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@de53cc3, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@26626124, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@12e5ca9b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@81314f4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@2cb43211, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@196a0de2, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@25e7ad46, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@35c3a9ba, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter@38ea21a9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@71a62e4b, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@693320a4, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4115ca41, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@281b4ca3]
2017-09-03 12:52:35 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository#0'
2017-09-03 12:52:38 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /index.jsp at position 5 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2017-09-03 12:52:39 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /index.jsp at position 5 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2017-09-03 12:52:39 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /index.jsp at position 5 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2017-09-03 12:52:47 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /login.jsp at position 5 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2017-09-03 12:52:49 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /j_spring_security_check at position 5 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2017-09-03 12:52:49 DEBUG CsrfFilter:95 - Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check
```

The methods to turn off CSRF protection I have tried including:

- Delete line: `<csrf/>` between`<http></http>`. Not work, still the
  same log methioning CSRF.
- Using Java-based configuration (I set breakpoint at the disable line
  however it never hit:

  ```java
  package infosec.utils;

  import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
  import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
  import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
  import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

  @EnableWebSecurity
  @Configuration
  public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
          http .csrf().disable();
       }
  }
  ```

Set breakpoint at `org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter`
   constructor, it was hit, however I have no idea where it was invoke:

[image]

Comment: @dur I am using Spring Security 3.2 The URL you show is the current version reference. In fact, https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-using shows that only if I explicitly use `    <csrf />` will the CSRF protection be turned on.

Comment: In the release notes for 3.2 it does say "CSRF protection is enabled by default with Java configuration. If you would like to disable CSRF, the corresponding Java configuration can be seen below.". Although I can see it looks like you've added the correct piece of code..

Comment: Did you try with xml config `<csrf disabled="true" />`

Comment: @dur I don't use SPring Boot. There are another two `<http>`: `<http pattern="login.jsp" security="none"/>
 <http pattern="index.jsp" security="none"/>`

Comment: Have tried, no work because this syntax is for Spring Security 4 and I am using Spring Security 3.2

Comment: @guo: It seems that your XML file is not used. If you have `<http pattern="login.jsp" security="none"/>` the CSRF protection should be disabled for `login.jsp`, but your log shows that it is enabled. Could you show more of your XML configuration?